# How to make 4 Components fit in constrain layout with equal space around and between them

Tags: android, android-xml, android-constraintlayout, android-cardview

I have 4 components(boxes) in an ConstraintLayout but the issues is the space between those components is more than the spaces around them
I know the issue is because of the margin i have given to each individual component, but what is the work around? to achieve the design given below

[image: What i want to achieve]

[image: What i already achieved]

Above is what i have achieved so far.

The main issue bothering is the space between those 4 components, it looks more away from each other than looking compact.

here is my xml code

```
            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true">

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
                android:id="@+id/view_horizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.5" />
            
            <!--                Top Left-->
            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/frameLayout_top_left"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/view_horizontal"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/frameLayout_top_right"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">
                
                <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_17sdp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_20sdp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_17sdp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_18sdp"
                    android:backgroundTint="@color/gradient_end_dashboard"
                    app:cardCornerRadius="20dp"
                    app:cardElevation="5dp"
                    app:cardMaxElevation="5dp" />

                <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_15sdp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_20sdp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_15sdp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_20sdp"
                    android:backgroundTint="@color/white"
                    app:cardCornerRadius="20dp"
                    app:cardElevation="5dp"
                    app:cardMaxElevation="5dp"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            </FrameLayout>

            <!--                Top Right-->
            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/frameLayout_top_right"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/view_horizontal"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/frameLayout_top_left"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">
                
                <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_17sdp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_20sdp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_17sdp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_18sdp"
                    android:backgroundTint="@color/gradient_end_dashboard"
                    app:cardCornerRadius="20dp"
                    app:cardElevation="5dp"
                    app:cardMaxElevation="5dp" />

                <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_15sdp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_20sdp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_15sdp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_20sdp"
                    android:backgroundTint="@color/white"
                    app:cardCornerRadius="20dp"
                    app:cardElevation="5dp"
                    app:cardMaxElevation="5dp"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            </FrameLayout>
            
            <!--                Bottom Left-->
            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/frameLayout_bottom_left"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/frameLayout_bottom_right"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/view_horizontal">
                
                <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_17sdp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_20sdp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_17sdp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_18sdp"
                    android:backgroundTint="@color/gradient_end_dashboard"
                    app:cardCornerRadius="20dp"
                    app:cardElevation="5dp"
                    app:cardMaxElevation="5dp" />

                <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_15sdp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_20sdp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_15sdp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_20sdp"
                    android:backgroundTint="@color/white"
                    app:cardCornerRadius="20dp"
                    app:cardElevation="5dp"
                    app:cardMaxElevation="5dp"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            </FrameLayout>

            <!--                Bottom Right-->
            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/frameLayout_bottom_right"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/frameLayout_bottom_left"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/view_horizontal">
                
                <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_17sdp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_20sdp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_17sdp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_18sdp"
                    android:backgroundTint="@color/gradient_end_dashboard"
                    app:cardCornerRadius="20dp"
                    app:cardElevation="5dp"
                    app:cardMaxElevation="5dp" />

                <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_15sdp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_20sdp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_15sdp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_20sdp"
                    android:backgroundTint="@color/white"
                    app:cardCornerRadius="20dp"
                    app:cardElevation="5dp"
                    app:cardMaxElevation="5dp"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            </FrameLayout>
            
        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: these boxes are fixed or are you using inside recyclerView?

Comment: @chandmohd They are fixed.

Comment: just divide `margin_end` of **top_left** `CardView` and `margin_start` of **top_right** `CardView` by two. you are applying margins twice. And for the bottom cards do the same

Comment: @dariushf i did that but that effects the inner image view, it no longer keeps itself centered.

Comment: you have to do the same to both cards on each side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using relative layout instead of frame layout and shift your layout/imageview inside the second cardView

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/rl_top_left"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/rl_bottom_left"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/rl_top_right"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:backgroundTint="#163042"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="7dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="7dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        app:cardCornerRadius="20dp"
        app:cardElevation="5dp"
        app:cardMaxElevation="5dp" />

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:backgroundTint="#ffffff"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="7dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        app:cardCornerRadius="20dp"
        app:cardElevation="5dp"
        app:cardMaxElevation="5dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:elevation="10dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_apple" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:text="Some Text"
                android:textColor="#abcdef"
                android:textSize="22sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:text="sub text"
                android:textColor="#009688"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />


        </LinearLayout>

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/rl_top_right"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/rl_bottom_right"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/rl_top_left"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:backgroundTint="#163042"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="7dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="7dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        app:cardCornerRadius="20dp"
        app:cardElevation="5dp"
        app:cardMaxElevation="5dp" />

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:backgroundTint="#ffffff"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="7dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        app:cardCornerRadius="20dp"
        app:cardElevation="5dp"
        app:cardMaxElevation="5dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:elevation="10dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_apple" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:text="Some Text"
                android:textColor="#abcdef"
                android:textSize="22sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:text="sub text"
                android:textColor="#009688"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />


        </LinearLayout>

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/rl_bottom_left"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/rl_bottom_right"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/rl_top_left">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:backgroundTint="#163042"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="7dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="7dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        app:cardCornerRadius="20dp"
        app:cardElevation="5dp"
        app:cardMaxElevation="5dp" />

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:backgroundTint="#ffffff"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="7dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        app:cardCornerRadius="20dp"
        app:cardElevation="5dp"
        app:cardMaxElevation="5dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:elevation="10dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_apple" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:text="Some Text"
                android:textColor="#abcdef"
                android:textSize="22sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:text="sub text"
                android:textColor="#009688"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />


        </LinearLayout>

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/rl_bottom_right"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/rl_bottom_left"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/rl_top_right">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:backgroundTint="#163042"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="7dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="7dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        app:cardCornerRadius="20dp"
        app:cardElevation="5dp"
        app:cardMaxElevation="5dp" />

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:backgroundTint="#ffffff"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="7dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        app:cardCornerRadius="20dp"
        app:cardElevation="5dp"
        app:cardMaxElevation="5dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:elevation="10dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_apple" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:text="Some Text"
                android:textColor="#abcdef"
                android:textSize="22sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:text="sub text"
                android:textColor="#009688"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />


        </LinearLayout>

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

No need to use that `GuideLine`. All your components must be constrained to each other to enable dynamic size of each component (since you are `0dp` for the width and height). The spacing between the components and between components and the edges of the screen can be defined using margins:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frameLayout_top_left"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/full_margin"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/full_margin"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/half_margin"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/half_margin"
        android:background="@android:color/black"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/frameLayout_bottom_left"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/frameLayout_top_right"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frameLayout_top_right"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/half_margin"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/full_margin"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/full_margin"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/half_margin"
        android:background="@android:color/black"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/frameLayout_bottom_right"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/frameLayout_top_left"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frameLayout_bottom_left"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/full_margin"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/half_margin"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/half_margin"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/full_margin"
        android:background="@android:color/black"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/frameLayout_bottom_right"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/frameLayout_top_left" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frameLayout_bottom_right"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/half_margin"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/half_margin"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/full_margin"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/full_margin"
        android:background="@android:color/black"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/frameLayout_bottom_left"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/frameLayout_top_right" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image: Result]

Comment: What are the values of full_margin and half_margin? Also if you see there are 2 cardviews inside my frame layout which is coausing the trouble.

Answer (score 0):

here's what i found-->

i included your cardviews inside the combination of linear and relative

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.5" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:background="#242425"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginBottom="-19dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >


        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginStart="17dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="17dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="18dp"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:cardCornerRadius="20dp"
            app:cardElevation="5dp"
            app:cardMaxElevation="5dp" />

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
     android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:backgroundTint="#FFFFFF"
            android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="20dp"
            app:cardElevation="5dp"
            app:cardMaxElevation="5dp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:background="#242425"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginBottom="-19dp"

        android:orientation="vertical" >


        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginStart="17dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="17dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="18dp"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:cardCornerRadius="20dp"
            app:cardElevation="5dp"
            app:cardMaxElevation="5dp" />

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:backgroundTint="#FFFFFF"
            android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="20dp"
            app:cardElevation="5dp"
            app:cardMaxElevation="5dp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.5" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:background="#242425"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical" >



        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginStart="17dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="17dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="18dp"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:cardCornerRadius="20dp"
            app:cardElevation="5dp"
            app:cardMaxElevation="5dp" />

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:backgroundTint="#FFFFFF"
            android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="20dp"
            app:cardElevation="5dp"
            app:cardMaxElevation="5dp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:background="#242425"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginStart="17dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="17dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="18dp"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            app:cardCornerRadius="20dp"
            app:cardElevation="5dp"
            app:cardMaxElevation="5dp" />

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:backgroundTint="#FFFFFF"
            android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="20dp"
            app:cardElevation="5dp"
            app:cardMaxElevation="5dp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]